# How to pass the CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES with multiple values in the ExternalProject_Add's CMAKE_ARGS

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I cannot find out a way how to create a fat library of my CMake ExternalProjects. The merit of the problem is how one can pass the -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING="x86_64;arm64" to the CMAKE_ARGS within the ExternalProject_Add definition.

One would expect that the following definition will work flawlessly. However, it seems that the content of the CMAKE_ARGS is being parsed somehow and this results in the malformed value in the resulting CMakeCache.txt.

*CMake Definition*

```
ExternalProject_Add(
        ext_libexiv2
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/Exiv2/exiv2.git
        GIT_TAG v0.27.6
        GIT_SHALLOW true
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING="x86_64;arm64" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DEXIV2_BUILD_SAMPLES=OFF -DEXIV2_BUILD_EXIV2_COMMAND=OFF
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
)
```

*CMakeCache.txt*

```
//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING="x86_64
```

I tried to escape the double quotes, use single quotes, escape the semicolon, but none of that worked out.

Certainly, I could do the fat library in the multiple steps, but I would prefer the cleaner solution. I will appreciate any direction you give me.

Comment: No, tripple escaping \\\; or single escaping doesn't work. It produces the same result as described in the original post.

Comment: Regarding the quote characters movement. I tried that including the escaped semicolon, triple escaped semiciolon and unescaped semicolon. The result is always the same CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=x86_64. In this case the value is not malformed by the quote character, but only the first arch from the given list is present.

Comment: Also, which cache file are you looking at? Are you looking at the cache file for the root buildsystem? Or the one for the generated buildsystem? (see [the `BINARY_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add))

Comment: I am looking at the one located in the <binary_dir>.

Comment: CMAKE_ARGS [=[-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=x86_64;arm64]=] results in the CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=x86_64

On the other hand

CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=[=[x86_64;arm64]=] results in the interesting CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=[=[x86_64;arm64]=] which is the first time when semicolon appeared in the caches value. However, this is not interpreted later, so this is not a solution. 

clang: error: invalid arch name '-arch [=[x86_64'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the [LIST_SEPARATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) option in the ExternalProject_Add definition.

```
ExternalProject_Add(
        ext_libexiv2
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/Exiv2/exiv2.git
        GIT_TAG v0.27.6
        GIT_SHALLOW true
        LIST_SEPARATOR |
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=x86_64|arm64 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DEXIV2_BUILD_SAMPLES=OFF -DEXIV2_BUILD_EXIV2_COMMAND=OFF
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
)
```

Then, the resulting cache value is the correct one.

```
//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=x86_64;arm64
```

Resulting libraries are really fat now.

```
➜  lib git:(prebuilt-components-replacement) ✗ lipo -info *.a
Architectures in the fat file: libexiv2-xmp.a are: x86_64 arm64
Architectures in the fat file: libexiv2.a are: x86_64 arm64
```

Comment: huh! weird that documentation doesn't seem to specify that such behaviour exists, but it does. The docs only seem to say that it can be used to convert semicolons to other characters and not the other way around... unless I'm misinterpreting it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue goes away if you switch to using `CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS` instead of `CMAKE_ARGS`. Like `CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=x86_64;arm64"`. From the docs:

> This is an alternate way of specifying cache variables where command line length issues may become a problem. The arguments are expected to be in the form `-Dvar:STRING=value`, which are then transformed into CMake [`set()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#command:set) commands with the `FORCE` option used. These `set()` commands are written to a pre-load script which is then applied using the `cmake -C` command line option.